# Table Javascript/JQuery not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, uitableview, html-table

I wanted to develop a table for which data is being fetched via a dataset and the rows are populated in a table with accordion category names.

#accordion-data is a blank div and this whole functionality is supposed to be inside it.

```
fetchDataAccordion(datasetNum) {
    const self = this;
    for (let c of self.categoryNames) {
        console.log(c);

        $("#accordion-data").append(`
             <div class="nested-accordion">
                         <h3>${c}</h3>
                         <div class="comment">
                             <table id="${c}-data">
                                 <colgroup>
                                         <col style="width:2%"/>
                                         <col style="width:6%"/>
                                         <col style="width:10%" />
                                         <col style="width:28%"/>
                                         <col style="width:16%"/>
                                 </colgroup>
                                 <tr class="bfm-rows">
                                     <th class="data-table-headers" rowspan="2">S.No</th>
                                     <th class="data-table-headers" rowspan="2">Category</th>
                                     <th class="data-table-headers" rowspan="2">BI Features</th>
                                     <th class="data-table-headers" rowspan="2">Details</th>
                                     <th class="data-table-headers" rowspan="2">User Weightage</th>
                                 </tr>`);

        self.fetchDataset(datasetNum).then(
            response => {
                let data = response.data;
                for (let i of data) {
                    if (i.Category == c) {
                        $("#accordion-data").append(`
                         <tr class='bfm-rows'>
                             <td style="text-align:center">${i.Sno}</td>
                             <td>${i.Category}</td>
                             <td>${i.BIFeatures}</td>
                             <td>${i.Details}</td>
                             <td>
                                 <select class="user-weightage-dropdown form-select" id="uw-${i.Sno}">

                                     <option value="-1" style="display:none">Select Weightage</option>
                                     <option value="0" class="user-weightage-options">0 - Donot Require this functionality</option>
                                     <option value="10" class="user-weightage-options">10 - This is nice to have functionality</option>
                                     <option value="20" class="user-weightage-options">20 - This is functionality is optional</option>
                                     <option value="30" class="user-weightage-options">30 - This functionality is needed</option>
                                     <option value="40" class="user-weightage-options">40 - Important functionlaity</option>
                                     <option value="50" class="user-weightage-options">50 - Extremely important functionality</option>
                                 </select>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                         `);
                        // }
                        $("#accordion-data").append(`</table>
                     </div>
                 </div>`);
                    }
                });

        }
    }
```

I also have a JQuery written as:

```
$('.nested-accordion').find('.comment').slideUp();
$('.nested-accordion').find('h3').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.comment').slideToggle(100);
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

I tried the above method but the table closes before the rows are populated resulting in following

[Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQY4S.png)

I want the table to have those rows in them too. Here the table is closing after the heading row and the below rows are without any parent table.

Kindly help!

Comment: Have you thought about creating the entire table structure beforehand, leaving just the `tbody` empty, to be filled once your request goes through, and you receive `data`?

Comment: I am struggling to understand what the specific problem is. I don't understand if there is an issue with constructing the table HTML or with the accordion functionality or both.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I would do here.

First, I would wrap the row of table headings (`<th>` elements) in a [`<thead>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) element. I'm not familiar with the `rowspan` attribute, but I get a wonky render if I don't include the `<thead>`.

Next, I would consider using a simple templating library so that I don't have to include all of that HTML markup in my JavaScript. [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) is one but one example.

When it comes to your accordion behavior, I think that it is broken due to the timing. I think that your jQuery code executes *before* your table rows have been populated. You could get around this by moving the jQuery code into your fetch handler, after `#accordion-data` has been fully appended to; however, my preferred approach would be to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Basically, we will tell jQuery to listen for clicks on our `#accordion-data` element whose source is `h3` elements:

```
$('#accordion-data').on('click', 'h3', function () {
    $(this).next('.comment').slideToggle(100);
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Finally, we might want to make sure that our `.comment` elements are collapsed (hidden) on their initial render, which we can do with CSS:

```
.comment {
  display: none;
}
```

Please see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/t6dmw5h2/) for the full example.